# Blinking a LED through a Web application

Tags: php, linux, web, embedded

I'm doing some experiments with some Linux-based embedded systems (Beaglebone, FriendlyARM mini6410, Embest Devkit 8000). I would like to write a web application using some kind of web technology PHP, Javascript,...whatever it is, whose purpose is just to blink a LED. I have to do this in order to see if I'm able to control some hardware resources through a Web application. I know that for the Beaglebone I can use node.js and bonescript but I would like to devise a solution that I can easily bring on other targets (with no or limited modifications to the application) since I have to replicate this on different embedded targets. I know that I have to go through sysfs in order to be able to control hardware resources from a user space application. I could do this in PHP (through sysfs I can drive a led just by opening and reading/writing files) or I could write a C CGI application wich does the same...But my question is, what are the other options? I would like to identify different possibilities for designing the web application in order to chose the proper one.

Comment: interesting question. would like to know more about this,following...

Comment: please check this may be helpful http://projects.sindrelindstad.com/how-to-led-arduino-php-proc/

Comment: Another solution which comes to my mind is to have a C application opening a socket and listening to a client PHP applciation on that socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I was doing it I would probably choose socket communication. Perhaps serial for really piddly pieces of hardware (that may not have an ethernet/wifi port). I would possibly enable support for both if the device is interchangable by abstracting the comms layer so the server could use sockets or serial connection strategies. Most all languages have support for both one way or another.

Answer (score 4):

write a small cgi. It can be even done with shell, where you can send commands to sysfs

You could make something like

```
#!/bin/sh

#this will parse the sent parameters
eval $(echo "$QUERY_STRING"|awk -F'&' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}')


# this has to be set to whatever you want
GPIO=22

echo $GPIO > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" /sys/class/gpio/gpio$GPIO/direction
echo 1 /sys/class/gpio/gpio$GPIO/value

cat << EOF
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>pin on</h1>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

finally you need to be sure that you have the rights to write on sysfs and that the webserver is configured to use the shell as the interpreter of the cgi

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little library called "php-gpio" : https://github.com/ronanguilloux/php-gpio

I suppose this might help for this kind of purpose.